# Bulk replacing div's content for hundreds of html files before upload

Tags: html, regex, batch-processing

I have a website with hundreds of static html files. I need to replace the facebook comments with disqus comments.

Here is what the divs that hold the comments look like now:

```
<div id="commentsBar">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://theinternet.io/pages/Sure-why-not.html" data-numposts="6" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</div>
```

I need to replace every div of the class "fb-comments" with another div of the form:

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script>

/**
*  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION     BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT:     https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*/
/*
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
};
*/
(function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');
s.src = 'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js';
s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
```

with PAGE_URL being the url that was listed in the "fb-comments" div.

Anybody have an idea of how to do this?

Most text editors I've looked at only allow you to find and replace, which won't work since the url in the fb-comments div are different for each html page.

Answer (score 0):

> It is frowned upon to do that with regular expression.

If there was no option, this expression might do that with a `preg_replace` in PHP for instance:

```
$re = '/<div class="fb-comments".*?<\/div>/s';
$str = '<div id="commentsBar">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://theinternet.io/pages/Sure-why-not.html" data-numposts="6" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</div>


<div id="commentsBar">
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="https://theinternet.io/pages/Sure-why-not.html" data-numposts="6" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
</div>';
$subst = '<div id="disqus_thread"></div><script>/***  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION     BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.*  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT:     https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables*//*var disqus_config = function () {this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page\'s canonical URL variablethis.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page\'s unique identifier variable};*/(function() { // DON\'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINEvar d = document, s = d.createElement(\'script\');s.src = \'https://EXAMPLE.disqus.com/embed.js\';s.setAttribute(\'data-timestamp\', +new Date());(d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);})();</script><noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dEBKs0/1/)